# URL Rewrite - How to convert part of the url to lowercase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm currently exploring the URL rewrite in IIS for some requirement to convert part of the URL from uppercase to lowercase.
As of the moment, I have this rule below.

```
<rule name="Redirect Vacancies to vacancies" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" >
  <match url="([a-zA-Z]{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{2})/Vacancies$" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}/vacancies" />
</rule>
```

Where if you type the url like `www.mydomain.com/en-sg/Vacancies` and hit Enter, this will redirected to `www.mydomain.com/en-sg/vacancies`. Notice, it convert the "**Vacancies**" to "**vacancies**".

My challenge now is, what if I have this URL `/Vacancies/Jobs` or `/Vacancies/Jobs/2018`. It seems like my existing rule is not working on this endpoint. What I want is that `/Vacancies` will be converted to lowercase but the `/Jobs` will still remain Camel case.

Appreciate any suggestions to the said requirement.

Cheers!

Comment: have you tried ` <rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">  
 <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />  
 <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>`

Comment: @arvind From the look of it, it will try to lowercase the entire URL. I just want to lowercase the part of the URL /Vacancies

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution now.
Please see below rule

```
<rule name="Redirect Vacancies to vacancies" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="([a-zA-Z]{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{2})/Vacancies" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/Vacancies/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{ToLower:{R:0}}/{C:1}" />
</rule>
```